# Poles of $\frac1{1-\sqrt{z}}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = \frac1{1-\sqrt{z}}$

where $\sqrt{z}$ is the principal branch.

$f$ has pole of order $m$ at $z_0=1$ iff $g(z) = 1-\sqrt{z}$ has zero of order $m$ at $z_0 = 1$.

By definition $g(z)$ has  zero of order $m$ at a point $z_0 = 1$ if $g$ is analytic at $z_0 = 1$ and the first $m-1$ derivatives vanish at $z_0$, but $f^{(m)}(z_0) \neq 0$ .

We have $g'(z) =-\frac1{2\sqrt{z}}$, so $g(z)$ is not analytic at $z_0=0$ because $g'(z)$ is not continuous at $z_0 = 0$.

So $f$ cannot have a pole.

However, if I take a different approach I get :

$f(z)=  \frac1{1-\sqrt{z}} = \frac{1+\sqrt{z}}{1-z}$ which has a pole of order 1 at $z_0=1$ since $z-1$ has a zero of order $1$ at $z_0=0$.

Can you explain this inconsistency?

Comment: The behaviour of $g$ near $0$ (where it has a branch point) is irrelevant for whether it has a pole at $1$ (which it does, since the principal branch of $\sqrt{z}$ is used).